# C++ hook or callback for C# project

Tags: c#, c++, assembly, dll, hook

I've a problem with hooking or installing callback.

I want to run a C# project, but i need to work with assembler so i created a C++ DLL with asm inline code. There i created jumps (Hooks with 5x NOP) to Hook some functions of a game and call Functions IN THE DLL.

All went great, but now there is a problem: I want to use these hooks in my C# project.

**All in all, what i want is:**

I start the dll from my C# project.
If a function inside the C++ dll is called ( e.g. `onPlayerDrink(std::string kindOfDrink)` ), a function inside the C# project should get called ( e.g. `onPlayerDrinkHook(string kindOfDrink)` )

Thanks for helping! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the easiest ways to do this is by using `C++/CLI` whereby you create a CLR, managed wrapper for your native, unmanaged C++ code. To do this create a new *Class Library* c++ project in Visual Studio.

In your C++/CLI code, make a simple wrapper for you unmanaged code as follows. Let's assume you have some class in your C++ code called `Native` with the following structure:

```
class Native {
public:
    Native();
    ~Native();

    int get_x() const noexcept;
    std::string get_y() const noexcept;
private:
    int x;
    std::string y;
};
```

Now in the C++/CLI wrapper, you can have the following:

```
public ref class Managed {
public:
    Managed() : native_ptr(new Native()) {}
    ~Managed() { delete native_ptr; }

    int GetX() {
        return native_ptr->get_x();
    }

    System::String^ GetY() {
        return gcnew String(native_ptr->get_y().c_str());
    }
private:
    Native* native_ptr;
};
```

Then you simply add the reference to this class library into your C# Project (go to *Add References* in the *Project Settings*), and you can then use the `Managed` class as you would use a normal C# class.

Comment: Thanks!, i installed the 'bridge' between C++ DLL and C# project with your solution. But now i recognize, thats it's not the complete solution: I need to call a method in my C# project when the extern engine in my C++ DLL calls a method... So not only using the functions in my C# project through these bridge, i need to callback it in some way. Do you have an answer? :)

Comment: @Alf21 I've typically always had a C# project calling native C++ code, not the other way round so I'm not sure on that one, but if I find anything then I'll update my answer with it here.

Comment: Thank you so much :) I also searched for a solution but there is no entry in the NET :/ I thought about callbacks but thats not that what i want. Could it be possible to manage a library which checks with assembler when a function is called and then it calls a function of the C# project?

Comment: @Alf21 You may want to look into this for what you require: [Interprocess Communications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, that's it!! I already thought about TCP but bidirectional pipes are better for me :)